# Работа usb rfid считывателя в режиме эмуляции клавиатуры в web приложении?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте интересует концептуальный подход к решению задачи работы usb-rfid считывателя в режиме эмуляции клавиатуры в веб приложении, суть в том что данные от касания карты с rfid считывателем поступают в любое активное текстовое поле в формате набора простых цифр в количестве от 10.

Задача: в том чтобы вне зависимости от фокуса на каком-либо текстовом поле вычленять данные код id карты и отправлять для последующей обработки.
Также стоит задача не помешать пользовательскому вводу в любом поле.

Замечание, что информация получаемая от считывателя имеет несколько отличительных свойств от пользовательского ввода : время вывода данных между 1 и последующей цифрой занимает не более 18 миллисекунд. т.е человек быстрее набрать не сможет. 
Спасибо.

Comment: контрольная цифра есть?